# Angular js while calling api I doesn't use the data in same function

Tags: angularjs

In this code I call the api.The requirement is to take the data from  3 api and aggregate all of them and display in table.

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
app.controller('PersonController', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.arr1 =[];
        $scope.arr2 = [];
        $scope.arr3 = [];
        $scope.temp ;


        function fetchAllBillable(){
          var me =$scope;         
             $http.get("http://echo.jsontest.com/insert-key-here/insert-value-here/key/value")
                 .then(function(response) {
                          $scope.temp = response.data;

                        console.log(me.temp);  

         });
         return $scope.temp;

the value of scope.temp is undefined
```

Comment: Did u get response from your service ?

Comment: Yes I get response in console.log(me.temp) which is written inside but doesn't get response in outside the http.get.

Comment: Make sure that your return statement should be inside function (as I am not able to see closed braces in your function ) and it is taking initial temp value.

Comment: Ya it is inside can you provide me reference with this code.The api is present here.I just need to get the array for perform the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but in the code you provided the closing tags are not right. Also, `$http` is an async call (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean) Stack Overflow article for more info), so the code after will execute before the request is done.

The code below should work.

```
app.controller('PersonController', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.arr1 =[];
        $scope.arr2 = [];
        $scope.arr3 = [];
        $scope.temp ;


        function fetchAllBillable(){
          var me =$scope;         
             $http.get("http://echo.jsontest.com/insert-key-here/insert-value-here/key/value")
                 .then(function(response) {
                          $scope.temp = response.data;

                        console.log(me.temp);  
                        return $scope.temp;

              });
       };
};
```

Comment: It give me undefined.Is there no way can i use this $scope.temp and after this function.

Comment: No there is not, that I am aware of, that is why there is .then. What happens if you try to return **response.data**? @sourabhlodha

Comment: var abc=fetchAllBillable(); alert(abc'); It print undefined .I need the value in abc for further operation.

Comment: What if you remove everything inside .then and write **return response.data;**

Comment: it provide same response undefined

Answer (score 1):

`$http` runs asynchronously, so the log statement outside `then` won't be available yet.

```
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($http, $scope) {
  $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(function(res) {
      $scope.data = res.data;
      console.log(res.data); // Object {...}
    });
  console.log($scope.data); // undefined
});
```

Edit:

You can merge $http calls with promise chaining or `$q.all`

```
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($http, $scope, $q) {
  var users = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1';
  var comments = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/'

  // Promise chaining
  $http.get(users)
    .then(function(res) {
      $scope.user = res.data;
      return $http.get(comments);
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      $scope.comments = res.data.slice(30)
    })

  // $q.all
  $q.all([
    $http.get(users),
    $http.get(comments)
  ]).then(function(resolves) {
    // resolves[0] is users
    // resolves[1] is comments
  })
});
```

Comment: In this Summary.html I have write a controller where data coming from 3 API as following
Billable API
1. psbillableOffshore
2. offshoreManager1
 
Buffer API
1. psbufferOffshore
2. OffshoreManager
 
Client API
1.offshoreManager
2.clientBillingOffshore1
3.clientBillingOffshore2
 
In all three api manager name is common.
 
 
I need to display in table. 
1.offshoreManager
2.psbillableOffshore
3. psbufferOffshore
4.clientBillingOffshore1
5.clientBillingOffshore2

Comment: In this code comments when we display on console.log(comments); it shows undefined.Can you look up the issue

Comment: My mistake, I haven't used `$q.all` in a while. The argument in the callback is an array of resolved data.

Comment: What if it is 3 API.Thanks Phix for help